# Unable to resolve module when trying to build

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I am trying to build main.jsbundle for my react native project for ios but i keep getting this error when i try to run this cmd :- react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios

[This is the error that i am getting when i run this command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPHO6.png)

Comment: Try again install @react-native-community/push-notification-ios and use autolinking (npx pod-install)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install @react-native-community/push-notification-ios and use autolinking (npx pod-install)

[@react-native-community/push-notification-ios](https://github.com/react-native-push-notification-ios/push-notification-ios)

Answer (score 0):

install this library

> yarn add @react-native-community/push-notification-ios

run this command into your terminal for auto linking

> npx pod-install

for more read this

```
https://github.com/react-native-push-notification-ios/push-notification-ios
```